# Getting Error 1064 when trying to import db file

Tags: mysql, dump, mysqlimport

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 33892 in file: 'contarproducts.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''\r\n        \r\n

How can I resolve this issue?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 33892 in file: 'contarproducts.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"100%\">\r\n  <tr>\r\n   <td ' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

1) You have this tagged as MySQL but then you seem to be running `MariaDB`, those aren't the same thing.

2) If there's an error in your SQL (which is what this is saying) and this SQL file was exported from the database it seems as though copying or moving the file cut it off and it didn't finish copying.  If the file doesn't get fully copied and the end of the file looks like `SELECT * FRO` then that will be a syntax error.

Try re-exporting the file before importing it again.